# Existence of primitive root satisfying a certain condition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

Let $l$ and $p$ be prime numbers such that $p|l-1$. Suppose there is an integer $r \in \mathbb Z$ such that $r^p \equiv 1 $ mod $l$. Can anyone please help me see why there exists a generator $s$ of $(\mathbb Z/ l \mathbb Z)^{\times}$ such that $r \equiv s^{ \frac{l-1}{p} } $ mod $l$? My attempt is as follows: pick any generator $t$ of $(\mathbb Z/ l \mathbb Z)^{\times}$. Then $t^x=r$ for some $0 < x \leq l-1$ and so $t^{px} \equiv  r^p \equiv 1$ mod $l$. Hence, $l-1$ divides $px$ but I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea about how to approach the proof. First, though, for better visual differentiation of $l$ as opposed to $1$, I'm replacing $l$ with $q$. Next, a small but required implicit detail is that $r \not\equiv 1 \pmod{q}$ since that also works with

$$r^p \equiv 1 \pmod{q} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

However, there is no generator $s$ where

$$r \equiv s^{\frac{q-1}{p}} \pmod{q} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

since the smallest positive power $i$ where $1 \equiv s^{i} \pmod{q}$ is $i = q - 1$. Next, here is a useful lemma:

---

**Lemma $1$:** For any generator $t$ of $(\mathbb Z/ q \mathbb Z)^{\times}$ and integer $j$ where $\gcd(j, q - 1) = 1$, then $u \equiv t^j \pmod{q}$ is also a generator.

**Proof:** Let $k_1$ and $k_2$ be two different integers where

$$u^{k_1} \equiv u^{k_2} \pmod{q} \implies u^{k_1 - k_2} \equiv 1 \pmod{q} \implies t^{j(k_1 - k_2)} \equiv 1 \pmod{q} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Since $t$ is a generator, this means

$$j(k_1 - k_2) \equiv 0 \pmod{q - 1} \implies q - 1 \mid j(k_1 - k_2) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

With $\gcd(j, q - 1) = 1$, this means $q - 1 \mid k_1 - k_2$. Thus, the congruences of the powers of $u$ repeat every $q - 1$ values, so the powers of $u^z$ for $0 \le z \lt q - 1$ are the $q - 1$ non-zero modulus values, which means $u$ must generate each one uniquely and, thus, is also a generator.

---

As you started, pick any generator $t$ of $(\mathbb Z/ q \mathbb Z)^{\times}$. Then for some integer $0 \lt x \lt q - 1$ (**note:** the second inequality should be $\lt$ rather than $\leq$), we get

$$t^x \equiv r \pmod{q}, \; 0 \lt x \lt q - 1 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

so this means

$$t^{px} \equiv r^p \equiv 1 \pmod{q} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

This gives, for some positive integer $m$,

$$px \equiv 0 \pmod{q - 1} \implies px = m(q - 1) \implies x = m\left(\frac{q - 1}{p}\right) \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

If $m = 1$, then let $s = t$ and we're done. Otherwise, since $x \lt q - 1$, then $px \lt p(q - 1)$, so $m \lt p$, which gives $2 \le m \le p - 1$. This means $m$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $p$, call it $n$. Next, for an integer $v$, have

$$u = vp + n \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Let $\gcd(n, q - 1) = d$. If $d = 1$, then set $v = 0$. Otherwise, let $p_i$ for $1 \le i \le a$ for some integer $a \gt 0$ be the set of distinct primes which divide $d$. Then, using the [$p$-adic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) function, set

$$v = \frac{q - 1}{p^{\nu_p(q - 1)}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{a}p_i^{{\nu_{p_i}(q - 1)}}\right)} \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

Note $1 \le u \lt q - 1$. Also, $\gcd(u, q - 1) = 1$ in all cases, since with $v = 0$ it's because $\gcd(n, q - 1) = 1$, while for $v \gt 0$, it's because $p \mid vp$ but $p \not\mid n$, all prime factors of $d$ divide $n$ but not $vp$, and all other prime factors (if any) of $q - 1$ divide $vp$ but not $n$.

From the right side of \eqref{eq7A}, multiply both sides by $u$, and use there exists an integer $b$ where $mn = bp + 1$ since $n$ is the multiplicative inverse of $p$, giving

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
ux & \equiv um\left(\frac{q - 1}{p}\right) \pmod{q - 1} \\
& \equiv (vp + n)m\left(\frac{q - 1}{p}\right) \pmod{q - 1} \\
& \equiv vm(q - 1) + nm\left(\frac{q - 1}{p}\right) \pmod{q - 1} \\
& \equiv (bp + 1)\left(\frac{q - 1}{p}\right) \pmod{q - 1} \\
& \equiv b(q - 1) + \frac{q - 1}{p} \pmod{q - 1} \\
& \equiv \frac{q - 1}{p} \pmod{q - 1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

Since $\gcd(u, q - 1)$, there's a multiplicative inverse $y$ of $u$ modulo $q - 1$. Since $\gcd(y, q - 1) = 1$, using Lemma $1$, this means there's a generator $s$ defined by

$$s \equiv t^{y} \pmod{q} \implies s^{u} \equiv t^{yu} \equiv t \pmod{q} \tag{11}\label{eq11A}$$

Using this in \eqref{eq5A}, and using \eqref{eq10A}, gives

$$r \equiv (s^{u})^{x} \equiv s^{ux} \equiv s^{\frac{q - 1}{p}} \pmod{q} \tag{12}\label{eq12A}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A bit surprised that this is long and not so easy to prove- my textbook stated this result in a proof without any explanation and so I thought it should be fairly straightforward to see.

Comment: @ShariputraJinasena You're welcome. The one main thing I'm aware that could have made my answer somewhat shorter & simpler if there is some sort of lemma or theorem I could used instead of stating and proving my Lemma $1$. I actually did a quick search on this site, but didn't find anything. Apart from my lemma, unless there's some sort of result which I'm unaware of which could be used to replace some other parts of my answer, perhaps something stated in your textbook, I don't think you can make the proof too much shorter.